# Extracting image from bounding box - selective search

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am learning how to properly use a selective search algorithm to create bounding boxes around an image, extract the smaller images within the bounding box and then run further analysis on the smaller images.

I am able to obtain the bounding boxes through the following, but how do I save/extract/export the images within each bounding box?

```
import skimage.data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import selectivesearch
import time
import io
import PIL
import scipy.misc

from skimage.io import imread
from PIL import Image
from skimage.transform import rescale, resize, downscale_local_mean


def main():

    # loading astronaut image


    # image = skimage.io.imread('/Users/vivek/Desktop/IMG_3350.JPG')
    # img = resize(image, (500,500), mode = 'reflect')

    img = skimage.io.imread('/Users/vivek/Downloads/IMG_3350_640x480.JPG')

    print ('image loaded')

    # perform selective search
    print ('initializing selective search')
    start = time.time()
    img_lbl, regions = selectivesearch.selective_search(
        img, scale=600, sigma=0.9, min_size=10)




    candidates = set()
    for r in regions:
        # excluding same rectangle (with different segments)
        if r['rect'] in candidates:
            continue
        # excluding regions smaller than 2000 pixels
        if r['size'] < 2000:
            continue
        # distorted rects
        x, y, w, h = r['rect']
        if w / h > 1.2 or h / w > 1.2:
            continue
        candidates.add(r['rect'])
    print ('selective search complete')

    end = time.time()
    totalTime = end - start
    print ('time taken to run this is : ' + str(totalTime))

    # draw rectangles on the original image
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(6, 6))
    ax.imshow(img)
    for x, y, w, h in candidates:
        print x, y, w, h
        rect = mpatches.Rectangle(
            (x, y), w, h, fill=False, edgecolor='red', linewidth=1)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        #plt.imsave("testerimage.jpg", None)

    plt.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of my resulting image with bounding boxes]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to get each rectangle using the lines

```
for x, y, w, h in candidates:
```

To get the image of the in this rectangle just do:

```
imgRect = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

Comment: Thankyou, doing so creates a single image. Is there a way to create multiple figure, one for each time a for loop runs

Comment: if you want to show the figure for each rectangle just do plt.figure() before you use plt.show(imgRect)

Comment: @Veejay can you please update your code and show how you fixed the problem?